# Spatialite Database library imported but init() error

Tags: android, android-sqlite, geospatial, spatialite

I imported the Spatialite Library from [here](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=spatialite-android-tutorial) 
And I am just trying to execute very simple queries but as soon as I am creating Database object, Its crashing by giving me this error

```
 No implementation found for void jsqlite.Database.internal_init() (tried Java_jsqlite_Database_internal_1init and Java_jsqlite_Database_internal_1init__)
```

I am tired making it work , I already tried solutions given by the folks over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36274100/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-in-jsqlite-database-internal-init-in-android-spat) stackoverflow thread

This is my complete error log

```
05-14 14:56:21.457 1421-1421/propelit.actionopps.com.propelit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: propelit.actionopps.com.propelit, PID: 1421
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void jsqlite.Database.internal_init() (tried Java_jsqlite_Database_internal_1init and Java_jsqlite_Database_internal_1init__)
    at jsqlite.Database.internal_init(Native Method)
    at jsqlite.Database.<clinit>(Database.java:956)
    at propelit.actionopps.com.propelit.MainActivity.initializeMapsAndPositioning(MainActivity.java:157)
    at propelit.actionopps.com.propelit.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MainActivity.java:811)
    at propelit.actionopps.com.propelit.MainActivity.checkPermissions(MainActivity.java:738)
    at propelit.actionopps.com.propelit.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:129)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6852)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2658)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2766)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1513)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6210)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:791)
```